# Performing update with Composer ... error: An error occurred

Tags: upgrades

I am getting this error when upgrading craft CMS, could anyone please assist.

```
<warning>Package "craftcms/vue-asset" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.</warning>
<warning>Package "yiisoft/yii2-shell" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.</warning>
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.4.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.4.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.14
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.13
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.11
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.4
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/homestead v7.20.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.37
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.36
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.34
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.29
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.27
```

`composer.json`:

```json
{
  "require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "3.5.8",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0",
    "craftcms/aws-s3": "1.2.11",
    "verbb/field-manager": "2.2.0",
    "craftcms/contact-form": "2.2.7",
    "craftcms/contact-form-honeypot": "1.0.2",
    "nystudio107/craft-cookies": "1.1.12",
    "matt-west/craft-recaptcha": "1.5.0",
    "fruitstudios/linkit": "1.1.11",
    "laravel/homestead": "^7.20",
    "craftcms/redactor": "2.7.4"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
  }
}
```

Full error:

```
Skipping database backup.
Performing update with Composer ... error: An error occurred

Output:

<warning>Package "craftcms/vue-asset" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.</warning>
<warning>Package "yiisoft/yii2-shell" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.</warning>
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.4.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.4.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.14
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.13
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.11
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.4
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/homestead v7.20.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.37
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.36
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.34
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.29
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.27
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.2.12
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.26
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.2.11
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.25
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.2.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.24
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.22
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.21
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.20
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.19
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.2.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.18
    - Installation request for craftcms/cms 3.7.27.2 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.7.27.2].
    - Installation request for laravel/homestead ^7.20 -> satisfiable by laravel/homestead[v7.20.0].
    - laravel/homestead v7.20.0 requires symfony/yaml ~3.3|~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/yaml[v3.3.6, v4.4.37, v4.4.36, v4.4.34, v4.4.29, v4.4.27, v4.4.26, v4.4.25, v4.4.24, v4.4.22, v4.4.21, v4.4.20, v4.4.19, v4.4.18, v4.4.17, v4.4.16, v4.4.15, v4.4.14, v4.4.13, v4.4.12, v4.4.11, v4.4.10, v4.4.9, v4.4.8, v4.4.7, v4.4.6, v4.4.5, v4.4.4, v4.4.3, v4.4.2, v4.4.1, v4.4.0, v4.3.11, v4.3.10, v4.3.9, v4.3.8, v4.3.7, v4.3.6, v4.3.5, v4.3.4, v4.3.3, v4.3.2, v4.3.1, v4.3.0, v4.2.12, v4.2.11, v4.2.10, v4.2.9, v4.2.8, v4.2.7, v4.2.6, v4.2.5, v4.2.4, v4.2.3, v4.2.2, v4.2.1, v4.2.0, v4.1.12, v4.1.11, v4.1.10, v4.1.9, v4.1.8, v4.1.7, v4.1.6, v4.1.5, v4.1.4, v4.1.3, v4.1.2, v4.1.1, v4.1.0, v4.0.15, v4.0.14, v4.0.13, v4.0.12, v4.0.11, v4.0.10, v4.0.9, v4.0.8, v4.0.7, v4.0.6, v4.0.5, v4.0.4, v4.0.3, v4.0.2, v4.0.1, v4.0.0, v3.4.47, v3.4.46, v3.4.45, v3.4.44, v3.4.43, v3.4.42, v3.4.41, v3.4.40, v3.4.39, v3.4.38, v3.4.37, v3.4.36, v3.4.35, v3.4.34, v3.4.33, v3.4.32, v3.4.31, v3.4.30, v3.4.29, v3.4.28, v3.4.27, v3.4.26, v3.4.25, v3.4.24, v3.4.23, v3.4.22, v3.4.21, v3.4.20, v3.4.19, v3.4.18, v3.4.17, v3.4.16, v3.4.15, v3.4.14, v3.4.13, v3.4.12, v3.4.11, v3.4.10, v3.4.9, v3.4.8, v3.4.7, v3.4.6, v3.4.5, v3.4.4, v3.4.3, v3.4.2, v3.4.1, v3.4.0, v3.3.18, v3.3.17, v3.3.16, v3.3.15, v3.3.14, v3.3.13, v3.3.12, v3.3.11, v3.3.10, v3.3.9, v3.3.8, v3.3.7, v3.3.5, v3.3.4, v3.3.3, v3.3.2, v3.3.1, v3.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.17, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.16, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.15, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.14, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.13, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.12, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.11, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.10, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.9, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.8, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.7, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.6, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.5, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.4, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.3, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.2, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.1, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.4.0, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.3.11, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.3.10, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.3.9, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.3.8, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.3.7, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.3.6, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.3.5, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.3.4, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.3.3, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.3.2, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.3.1, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.3.0, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.2.12, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.2.11, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.2.10, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.2.9, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.2.8, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.2.7, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.2.6, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.2.5, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.2.4, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.2.3, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.2.2, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.2.1, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.2.0, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.1.12, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.1.11, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.1.10, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.1.9, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.1.8, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.1.7, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.1.6, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.1.5, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.1.4, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.1.3, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.1.2, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.1.1, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.1.0, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.15, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.14, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.13, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.12, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.11, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.10, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.9, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.8, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.7, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.6, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.5, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.4, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.3, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.2, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.1, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v4.0.0, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.47, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.46, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.45, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.44, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.43, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.42, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.41, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.40, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.39, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.38, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.37, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.36, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.35, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.34, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.33, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.32, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.31, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.30, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.29, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.28, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.27, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.26, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.25, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.24, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.23, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.22, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.21, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.20, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.19, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.18, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.17, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.16, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.15, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.14, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.13, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.12, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.11, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.10, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.9, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.8, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.7, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.6, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.5, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.4, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.3, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.2, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.1, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.0, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.18, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.17, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.16, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.15, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.14, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.13, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.12, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.11, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.10, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.9, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.8, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.7, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.6, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.5, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.4, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.3, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.2, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.1, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.3.0, v5.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v5.2.1, v3.3.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v5.2.1, v3.3.6].
    - craftcms/cms 3.7.27.2 requires symfony/yaml ^5.2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/yaml[v5.4.3, v5.4.2, v5.4.0, v5.3.14, v5.3.13, v5.3.11, v5.3.6, v5.3.4, v5.3.3, v5.3.2, v5.3.0, v5.2.14, v5.2.12, v5.2.11, v5.2.10, v5.2.9, v5.2.7, v5.2.5, v5.2.4, v5.2.3, v5.2.2, v5.2.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.2.2

<warning>Running update with --no-dev does not mean require-dev is ignored, it just means the packages will not be installed. If dev requirements are blocking the update you have to resolve those problems.</warning>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually caused by some outdated dependencies or some mismatch between your installed dependencies and your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files. It could also be that the Craft updater is trying to update the specified packages for some reason, but they're not installed, so Composer is throwing a warning. For example, if you check the [craftcms/vue-asset](https://github.com/craftcms/vue-asset) repository, you can see it's deprecated and should not be used anymore.

To fix this error, you need to figure out if this package is required by either your project itself or by another dependency (for instance, a plugin) – probably the latter. You can ask Composer for this information:

```bash
composer why craftcms/vue-asset
```

If the package is installed in your project itself, you can simply remove it. Of course you'll need to check if it's actually in use and if so, update this part of the codebase to use the recommended alternative instead.

```bash
composer remove craftcms/vue-asset
```

If the package is required by a dependency, you need to either remove or update that dependency.

---

To find out more about the errors you're getting, make sure to run the update method from a shell, not from the backend, so you can see all error messages:

```bash
php craft update all
```

You can also try to update through Composer directly, this will tell you what conflicts are preventing the update:

```bash
composer update --with-all-dependencies --dry-run
```

If this succeeds with no problems, run it again without `--dry-run`.

---

As a sidenote, the error you listed doesn't exist in the current Composer version any more, make sure to update to the latest version:

```bash
composer self-update
```

---

#### Update regarding version conflicts

The error messages you're receiving means there's a conflict between some dependencies. To resolve this, you need to update and/or remove dependencies until you have a set of dependencies that resolves to an installable set of dependencies.

In your concrete case, it looks like the problem is Laravel Homestead. Your `composer.json` requires `laravel/homestead:^7.2.0`, which is [very outdated](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases). This version requires `symfony/yaml ~3.3|~4.0` while the version of `craftcms/craft` you're trying to update to [requires the same package in version `^5.2.1`](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/v3/composer.json#L50). Satisfying both of those isn't possible, so Composer can't resolve your dependencies.

Either update or remove `laravel/homestead`, then try the Craft update again. If you get more errors, check which dependency is causing them and resolve the problem in the same way. Keep going until you have a set of dependencies that will update cleanly.

Comment: I am getting this error when i tried to remove the package 
Removal failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: @JohnC You can't remove a package unless it's installed in your project directly, if you try to remove a package that is installed by a dependency you would get this error. Try the `why` command (see above) to find out which dependency is installing the packages that are causing trouble and then remove that dependency.

Comment: I tried the why command but its showing the package is not installed.

Comment: @JohnC Then you don't need to remove it. What is the problem?

Comment: I am trying to upgrade the CraftCMS but I am getting this error and its blocking the upgrade. This is the issue I am getting now on the site, can you please help us to resolve this.

Comment: Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.4.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.4.2

Comment: - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v5.3.4
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/homestead v7.20.0

Comment: <warning>Package "craftcms/vue-asset" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.</warning>
<warning>Package "yiisoft/yii2-shell" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.</warning>
Loading composer repositories with package information

Comment: @JohnC What command is producing this error for you? Have you tried the steps recommended in my answer? Please add your `composer.json` to your answer as well, this will make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: I am using php craft update craft command to update and I am getting this erro. Yes I tried the answer and got the issue

Comment: @JohnC I've updated my answer with some guidance on resolving the dependency version conflicts you're seeing.

Comment: @MortizLost I have removed the laravel/homestead and again tried the update, got the error

Comment: applying m210613_145522_sortable_global_sets
    > add column sortOrder smallint UNSIGNED AFTER `fieldLayoutId` to table {{%globalsets}} ...Exception: SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'sortOrder'

Comment: @JohnC That's a completely separate issue, please open a new question for this. If your current problem is solved, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @MozitzLost
I have removed the laravel/homestead application after that, I am getting this issue.